# R - Set color variables of a bubble chart

Tags: r, bubble-chart, googlevis

how to change the color of the bubble depending on a factor variable? My code is the following:

```
library(googleVis)
motion <- gvisMotionChart(temp1,
                      idvar="Location",
                      timevar="Year",
                      xvar = "Population_thousand", yvar = "AvgHouseholdDisposableIncome",
                      colorvar = "Country",
                      sizevar = "BubbleSize",
                      options=list(height = 620, width = 1280))
plot(motion)
```

Today the colors are not nice and I would like to put nicer colors depending on the country.

[image]

Comment: @ProgrammerMan I doubt this is a dupe, ggplot == googleVis?

Comment: From the "Introduction to googleVis 0.6.2" page 36 (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/googleVis.pdf):   No, unfortunately not. The colours are set by the Google Charts API and cannot be changed by the user.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)